# Add a Custom Button in Xcode 4

Tags: interface-builder, xcode4

I am trying to add a custom button in the new Xcode 4 Interface Builder. In the old one with Xcode 3, you could just drag in any of the button types, change their style to custom, and add in your own image to make a custom button. Now it seems the "custom" style is missing, and when the image is changed, it is just overlaid on one of the other button types. How can I add custom buttons now?

EDIT: I see that the custom button option exists on the iOS Xcode 4 still, but it seems to now be gone for a OSX Cocoa application. Why is this and how can I recreate this funcionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that you can recreate the custom button by making a button with Style: Square, Type: Switch, Visual: Bordered and Transparent unchecked, and then add your own image in the Image box.